# PHP - Read CSV File & Concatenate Columns into Delimited Rows and Output into New File

Tags: php, csv, output, concatenation

Good Day All,

Trying to take a stab at bettering my PHP and reducing the amount of tedious work by automating some of my work. I'm trying to write a PHP file that takes a CSV and converts the columns into delimited rows.

Example:

> 12:11:00  Mark    Hello
>
> 12:23:10  Jane    Hi there!
>
> 12:24:32  Bob     What's up?
>
> In the output CSV, it should be one row with three columns that look
> like this [Delimiter is |||]:
>
> 12:11:00|||12:23:10|||12:24:32,Mark|||Jane|||Bob,Hello|||Hi
> there!|||What's up?

I saw similar code on here but it concatenates all into one lump and I tried to mod it to make it into three columns.

I am not the author of this code as I scraped it from a post on Stack Exchange and tried to mod it for my use case. If someone could help me with this, I would be most appreciative!

```
<?php

$rows = [];

$file = fopen("test.csv", "r"); // open your file

while (!feof($file)) { // read file till the end

    $row = fgetcsv($file); // get current row as an array of elements

    if (!empty($row)) { // check that it's not the empty row

        array_push($rows, $row); // store row in array
    }
}

fclose($file);

for ($r1 = 0; $r1 < count($rows); $r1++) {
echo $rows[$r1][0] . '_' . PHP_EOL;}


for ($r2 = 0; $r2 < count($rows); $r2++) {
echo $rows[$r2][1] . '_' . PHP_EOL; }


for ($r3 = 0; $r3 < count($rows); $r3++) {
echo $rows[$r3][2] . PHP_EOL;}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("test.csv", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$content = fread($myfile, filesize("test.csv"));
fclose($myfile);

$times = $names = $texts = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $content) as $line) {
    $words = explode(' ', $line); // separate line by spaces

    $times[] = $words[0]; // first string
    $names[] = $words[1]; // second string
    $texts[] = implode(' ', array_splice($words, 2)); // all remaining strings
}

$output = implode('|||', $times).','.implode('|||', $names).','.implode('|||', $texts);

echo $output."\n";
```

->

```
12:11:00|||12:23:10|||12:24:32,Mark|||Jane|||Bob,Hello|||Hi there!|||What's up?
```